# pip cannot install any packages or even update

Tags: python, pip, centos

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUh1L.png)

I am new to Linux.When i install CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-2009 via VM,yum install python and pip,the promble occurred.
my command line history
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3Vi4.png)

Comment: What is the python version installed ? What is the pip version installed ?

Note that pip2 is for python 2.x and pip3 is for python 3.x

Comment: Oof, _please_ don't `pip install` things as `root`, especially if you aren't using a virtual environment! Mixing system-provided Python packages and `pip install`ed ones in the same environment is a great way to break your system.

Comment: oh,thanks your reminder.My problem has solved.But i still don't know why.I used Python 2.x at the begining.try install pip via python2 too, but still failed even more error messages.At last, i install python3 which bring pip3 default.